# Compute the kangaroo sequence

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, arithmetic, array

#### Backstory

<sup>Disclaimer: May contain made up information about kangaroos.</sup>

Kangaroos traverse several stages of development. As they grow older and stronger, they can jump higher and longer, and they can jump more times before they get hungry.

In stage **1**, the kangaroo is very little and cannot jump at all. Despite this, is constantly requires nourishment. We can represent a stage **1** kangaroo's activity pattern like this.

```
o
```

In stage **2**, the kangaroo can make small jumps, but not more than **2** before it gets hungry. We can represent a stage **2** kangaroo's activity pattern like this.

```
 o o
o o o
```

After stage **2** the kangaroo improves quickly. In each subsequent stage, the kangaroo can jump a bit higher (1 unit in the graphical representation) and twice as many times. For example, a stage **3** kangaroo's activity pattern looks like this.

```
  o   o   o   o
 o o o o o o o o
o   o   o   o   o
```

All that jumping requires energy, so the kangaroo requires nourishment after completing each activity pattern. The exact amount required can be calculated as follows.

1. Assign each **o** in the activity pattern of a stage **n** kangaroo its height, i.e., a number from **1** to **n**, where **1** corresponds to the ground and **n** to the highest position.
2. Compute the sum of all heights in the activity pattern.

For example, a stage **3** kangaroo's activity pattern includes the following heights.

```
  3   3   3   3
 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
1   1   1   1   1
```

We have five **1**'s, eight **2**'s, and four **3**'s; the sum is **5·1 + 8·2 + 4·3 = 33**.

#### Task

Write a full program or a function that takes a positive integer **n** as input and prints or returns the nutritional requirements per activity of a stage **n** kangaroo.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf); may the shortest answer in bytes win!

#### Examples

```
 1 ->     1
 2 ->     7
 3 ->    33
 4 ->   121
 5 ->   385
 6 ->  1121
 7 ->  3073
 8 ->  8065
 9 -> 20481
10 -> 50689
```

Comment: I downvoted because I don't like challenges where a complicated setup comes down to a straightforward formula to golf.

Comment: While all answers so far have used the formula, I'm convinced that there are other ways to attack the problem.

Comment: Is there a challenge to generate the ascii art output of this sequence?

Comment: @miles Not sure. Kinda hard to search for.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha could not find a shorter version, `http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E(n-1)*(n%5E2-1)%2B1` (Weird markup because a regular URL gets messed up)

Comment: @Konijn Certain chars need to be escaped or converted to `%[hex value]`. Also, you should use HTTPS in your links. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E(n-1)%2A(n%5E2-1)%2B1

Comment: @miles There is now: [Leaping Kangaroos](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/107600/12012)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
²’æ«’‘
```

Uses the formula (*n*<sup>2</sup> - 1) 2<sup>*n* - 1</sup> + 1 to compute each value. @Qwerp-Derp's was kind enough to provide a [proof](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96386/6710).

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=wrLigJnDpsKr4oCZ4oCY&input=&args=MTA) or [Verify all test cases.](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=wrLigJnDpsKr4oCZ4oCYClLFvMOH4oKsJEc&input=&args=MTA)

### Explanation

```
²’æ«’‘  Input: n
²       Square n
 ’      Decrement
  æ«    Bit shift left by
    ’     Decrement of n
     ‘  Increment
```

Comment: Did you do it by hand, or auto-generate it?

Comment: Found it using J and searching OEIS, then simplified it by hand

Comment: I consider my own answer non-competing, so I have accepted this one.

Answer (score 17):

## Coffeescript, 19 bytes

```coffee
(n)->(n*n-1<<n-1)+1
```

Edit: Thanks to Dennis for chopping off 6 bytes!

The formula for generating Kangaroo numbers is this:

[image]

### Explanation of formula:

The number of `1`'s in `K(n)`'s final sum is `2^(n - 1) + 1`.

The number of `n`'s in `K(n)`'s final sum is `2^(n - 1)`, so the sum of all the `n`'s is `n * 2^(n - 1)`.

The number of any other number (`d`) in `K(n)`'s final sum is `2^n`, so the sum of all the `d`'s would be `d * 2^n`.

- Thus, the sum of all the other numbers `= (T(n) - (n + 1)) * 2^n`, where `T(n)` is the triangle number function (which has the formula `T(n) = (n^2 + 1) / 2`).

  Substituting that in, we get the final sum

  ```
    (((n^2 + 1) / 2) - (n + 1)) * 2^n
  = (((n + 1) * n / 2) - (n + 1)) * 2^n
  = ((n + 1) * (n - 2) / 2) * 2^n
  = 2^(n - 1) * (n + 1) * (n - 2)
  ```

When we add together all the sums, we get `K(n)`, which equals

```
  (2^(n - 1) * (n + 1) * (n - 2)) + (2^(n - 1) + 1) + (n * 2^(n - 1))
= 2^(n - 1) * ((n + 1) * (n - 2) + n + 1) + 1
= 2^(n - 1) * ((n^2 - n - 2) + n + 1) + 1
= 2^(n - 1) * (n^2 - 1) + 1
```

... which is equal to the formula above.

Comment: Why does PPCG not have mathjax?

Comment: @Jonathan We did, but it caused to many problems with dollar signs in code blocks.

Comment: @JonathanAllan There were issues but it was nice for a while [1](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5056/do-we-really-want-latex-mathjax-right-now) [2](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/292/latex-mathjax-support-would-be-nice) [3](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7877/remove-mathjax-support-on-meta)

Comment: Vanilla JS is two bytes shorter: `n=>(n*n-1<<n-1)+1`

Comment: Wait, MathJax doesn't work here? Or why is the equation an image?

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek Read Dennis's and miles's comments for details.

Answer (score 7):

## Java 7, 35 bytes

```
int c(int n){return(n*n-1<<n-1)+1;}
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŒḄ¡S
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=xZLhuITCoVM&input=&args=MTA) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=xZLhuITCucKhUwoxMFLCtcW8w4figqxH&input=).

#### How it works

```
ŒḄ¡S  Main link. Argument: n (integer)

ŒḄ    Bounce; turn the list [a, b, ..., y, z] into [a, b, ..., y, z, y, ..., b, a].
      This casts to range, so the first array to be bounced is [1, ..., n].
      For example, 3 gets mapped to [1, 2, 3, 2, 1].
  ¡   Call the preceding atom n times.
      3 -> [1, 2, 3, 2, 1]
        -> [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1]
        -> [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1]
   S  Compute the sum.
```

Comment: Oh, so *that's* what bounce does. I wish I'd known that before adding that exact operation to Japt a few days ago :P

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, <s>25</s> 23 bytes

```
lambda x:(x*x-1<<x-1)+1
```

Used miles's formula.

Thanks to Jonathan Allan for -2 bytes.

Comment: You don't need `~-x`. You can use `x-1` as well (not any shorter), since subtraction has a higher precedence than shifting.

Comment: @mbomb007 I know, but the code Jonathan Allan gave me used `~-x`, so I decided to leave it unchanged. Well, it seems everyone prefers `x-1`, though (Dennis also said that exact thing).

Comment: IMHO, It's more readable, and it looks more like the mathematical formula used.

Comment: @mbomb007 Oh you mean the very recently added bounty? If so, I changed it. But, I might raise some arguments then... I could have also done `-~(x*x-1<<~-x)` for the record, but `-1` still exists, so I don't like to blend code...

Comment: I mean nothing about the bounty. The math formula used in [this answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96386/34718). We write "minus 1" as `- 1`.

Comment: @mbomb007 I didn't think there would have been be rage by 2 people about this minor thing :P I have changed it now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46991/discussion-between-mbomb007-and-erik-the-golfer).

Answer (score 4):

## Lua, 105 bytes

```
s=tonumber(arg[1])e=1 for i=1,s>1 and 2^(s-1)or 0 do e=e+1 for j=2,s-1 do e=e+j*2 end e=e+s end print(e)
```

De-golfed:

```
stage = tonumber(arg[1])
energy = 1
for i = 1, stage > 1 and 2 ^ (stage - 1) or 0 do
    energy = energy + 1
    for j = 2, stage - 1 do
        energy = energy + j * 2
    end
    energy = energy + stage
end
print(energy)
```

Entertaining problem!

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf!

Comment: s=tonumber(arg[1]) can be swapped out for s=... to save some bytes. ... stores the arg table unpacked, in this case, returns arg[1]. And lua's strings will act like numbers of they only contain a valid number constructor, which we can assume the input is in this case.

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, 11 bytes

```
ri_2#(\(m<)
```

[Try it Online.](//cjam.aditsu.net#code=ri_2%23(%5C(m%3C)&input=3)

Explanation:

```
r           e# Get token.       ["A"]
 i          e# Integer.         [A]
  _         e# Duplicate.       [A A]
   2#       e# Square.          [A A^2]
     (      e# Decrement.       [A A^2-1]
      \     e# Swap.            [A^2-1 A]
       (    e# Decrement.       [A^2-1 A-1]
        m<  e# Left bitshift.   [(A^2-1)*2^(A-1)]
          ) e# Increment.       [(A^2-1)*2^(A-1)+1]
            e# Implicit output.
```

Comment: Only if I didn't need `ri`...

Answer (score 4):

## [Actually](http://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 8 bytes

```
;²D@D╙*u
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=O8KyREBE4pWZKnU&input=Mw)

Explanation:

This simply computes the formula `(n**2 - 1)*(2**(n-1)) + 1`.

```
;²D@D╙*u
;         duplicate n
 ²        square (n**2)
  D       decrement (n**2 - 1)
   @      swap (n)
    D     decrement (n-1)
     ╙    2**(n-1)
      *   product ((n**2 - 1)*(2**(n-1)))
       u  increment ((n**2 - 1)*(2**(n-1))+1)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [GolfScript](//golfscript.com), 11 bytes

```
~.2?(2@(?*)
```

[Try it online!](//golfscript.tryitonline.net#code=fi4yPygyQCg_Kik&input=Mw)

Thanks Martin Ender (8478) for removing 4 bytes.

Explanation:

```
            Implicit input                 ["A"]
~           Eval                           [A]
 .          Duplicate                      [A A]
  2         Push 2                         [A A 2]
   ?        Power                          [A A^2]
    (       Decrement                      [A A^2-1]
     2      Push 2                         [A A^2-1 2]
      @     Rotate three top elements left [A^2-1 2 A]
       (    Decrement                      [A^2-1 2 A-1]
        ?   Power                          [A^2-1 2^(A-1)]
         *  Multiply                       [(A^2-1)*2^(A-1)]
          ) Increment                      [(A^2-1)*2^(A-1)+1]
            Implicit output                []
```

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica, 15 bytes

```
(#*#-1)2^#/2+1&
```

There is no bitshift operator, so we need to do the actual exponentiation, but then it's shorter to divide by 2 instead of decrementing the exponent.

Answer (score 3):

## C, 26 bytes

As a macro:

```
#define f(x)-~(x*x-1<<~-x)
```

As a function (27):

```
f(x){return-~(x*x-1<<~-x);}
```

Comment: The macro version will produce incorrect results if the parameter is an expression. Consider `f(1+2)`.

Comment: @kasperd The parameter will not be an expression. *Write a full program or a function that takes **a positive integer n** as input and prints or returns the nutritional requirements per activity of a stage **n** kangaroo.*

Comment: Your quote says a **full program** or **a function**. But **a macro** is neither.

Comment: @kasperd Basically, I think it's like a function, but without evaluation. Also, I have provided a "real" function below, if that's what you want.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
n<¹<o*>
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=bjzCuTxvKj4&input=MTA)

**Explanation**

```
n<        # n^2
     *    # *
  ¹<o     # 2^(n-1)
      >   # + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 7 bytes

```
UqGqW*Q
```

Uses the formula from other answers.

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=VXFHcVcqUQ&input=Mw)

```
U    % Implicit input. Square
q    % Decrement by 1
G    % Push input again
q    % Decrement by 1
W    % 2 raised to that
*    % Multiply
Q    % Increment by 1. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 18 bytes

```
n=>(n*n-1<<n-1)+1;
```

Anonymous function based on [Qwerp-Derp](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/49561/qwerp-derp)'s excellent mathematical analysis.

Full program with test cases:

```
using System;

namespace KangarooSequence
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Func<int,int>f= n=>(n*n-1<<n-1)+1;

            //test cases:
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(i + " -> " + f(i));
            /* will display:
            1 -> 1
            2 -> 7
            3 -> 33
            4 -> 121
            5 -> 385
            6 -> 1121
            7 -> 3073
            8 -> 8065
            9 -> 20481
            10 -> 50689
            */
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 30 bytes

```
@cmd/cset/a"(%1*%1-1<<%1-1)+1"
```

Well, it beats Java anyway.

Answer (score 2):

## [Oasis](http://github.com/Adriandmen/Oasis), 9 bytes

```
2n<mn²<*>
```

I'm surprised there isn't a built-in for `2^n`.

[Try it online!](http://oasis.tryitonline.net/#code=Mm48bW7CsjEtKj4&input=&args=OQ)

#### Explanation:

```
2n<m        # 2^(n-1) (why is m exponentiation?)
    n²<     # n^2-1
       *    # (2^(n-1))*(n^2-1)
        >   # (2^(n-1))*(n^2-1)+1
```

Comment: Exponentiation in Dutch is `m`achtsverheffing, that and lack of creativity. Also, a lot of operators haven't been implemented yet, due to lazyness and procrastination.

Answer (score 1):

### Racket 33 bytes

Using formula explained by @Qwerp-Derp

```
(+(*(expt 2(- n 1))(-(* n n)1))1)
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (f n)
  (+ (*(expt 2
            (- n 1))
      (-(* n n)
        1))
    1))
```

Testing:

```
(for/list((i(range 1 11)))(f i))
```

Output:

```
'(1 7 33 121 385 1121 3073 8065 20481 50689)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 8 bytes

```
h.<t*QQt
```

[pyth.herokuapp.com](//pyth.herokuapp.com?code=h.%3Ct%2aQQt&input=3&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3)

Explanation:

```
     Q   Input
      Q  Input
    *    Multiply
   t     Decrement
       t Decrement the input
 .<      Left bitshift
h        Increment
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 21 bytes

@Qwerp-Derp basically did the heavy lifting.

Because of the precedence in ruby, it seems we need some parens:

```
->(n){(n*n-1<<n-1)+1}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 23 bytes

```
(n:Int)=>(n*n-1<<n-1)+1
```

Uses bit shift as exponentiation

Answer (score 1):

### R, 26 bytes

Shamelessly applying the formula

```
n=scan();2^(n-1)*(n^2-1)+1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 11 bytes

```
1-<:2&*1-*:
```

Based on the same formula found [earlier](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96382/6710).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#@5@mYGulYKhrY2WkpmWoq2XFlZqcka@goaOXpmSgqWBnpZCpp2Bo8P8/AA)

### Explanation

```
1-<:2&*1-*:  Input: integer n
         *:  Square n
       1-    Subtract it from 1
  <:         Decrement n
    2&*      Multiply the value 1-n^2 by two n-1 times
1-           Subtract it from 1 and return
```

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy (22 Bytes)

```
{(it--**2-1)*2**it+1}​
```

Does not preserve `n`, but uses the same formula as all others in this competition. Saved 1 byte with decrements, due to needed parenthesis.

### Test

```
(1..10).collect{(it--**2-1)*2**it+1}​
```

> [1, 7, 33, 121, 385, 1121, 3073, 8065, 20481, 50689]

Answer (score 0):

## JS-Forth, 32 bytes

Not super short, but it's shorter than Java. This function pushes the result onto the stack. This requires JS-Forth because I use `<<`.

```
: f dup dup * 1- over 1- << 1+ ;
```

[**Try it online**](https://repl.it/DzVG)